# Laravel save timestamp field to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I have timestamp field

`$table->timestamp('age')->nullable()->default(null);`

I need save is field is value to database.

```
  $dateOfBirth = Carbon::now()->subYears(intval($row['age']));

  return Customer::updateOrCreate(['id' => $row['id']],['id' => $row['id'],
             'name' => $row['name'],
             'age' =>$dateOfBirth->getTimestamp(),
             'email' => $row['email']]);
```

But got error

> Incorrect datetime value: '871238720' for column 'age' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `customers` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Annika Kane, 871238720, malattia@hotmail.com, 2022-08-10 18:45:20, 2022-08-10 18:45:20))

How fix it?

Comment: `'age' => $dateOfBirth`; don't do `->getTimestamp()`. Laravel automatically handles Carbon instances when inserting them into the database.

Comment: Error  Incorrect datetime value: '1956-08-10 19:06:01' for column 'age' at row 1 (SQL: update `customers` set `age` = 1956-08-10 19:06:01, `customers`.`updated_at` = 2022-08-10 19:06:01 where `id` = 21)

Comment: One caveat to @TimLewis comment, you also have ensure your model is properly configured so that Laravel knows it's supposed to be a timestamp. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Comment: @miken32 Oh right, it doesn't auto detect that for new timestamp fields, only the existing/expected ones, like `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Comment: Also, timestamps are designed to store dates since 1970. You should probably just set it to a datetime column and save yourself the trouble. See for example output from MySQL to `SELECT unix_timestamp('1956-08-10 19:06:01')` (returns `NULL`) vs `SELECT unix_timestamp('1976-08-10 19:06:01')` (returns `208566361`)

Comment: Not related to your question, but I advise you to edit your questions, as have an E-Mail address printed in your error. Always check, if you post sensitive data, when post an error stack or similar.

Comment: You should not use timestamp for a date of birth.  As has been mentioned, its not possible to record the DOB for anyone born before 1970